# What am I doing wrong trying to monitor a Tweetstream daemon with God?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, god

I'm trying to monitor a tweetstream daemon with God.. my god config is very simple:

```
path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "tweet.rb"
  w.start = "bundle exec ruby #{path}/tweet.rb start"
  w.keepalive
end
```

While my tweetstream daemon is a standard implementation of that as well.. when I start the god process it seems to cycle through starting the process over and over and over... I'm not sure if its failing to start, or if its starting then shutting down.. or I guess I don't know how to interpret this.. any help is appreciated:  some sample output:

```
I [2012-01-22 23:43:53]  INFO: tweet.rb moved 'up' to 'start'
I [2012-01-22 23:43:53]  INFO: tweet.rb [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2012-01-22 23:43:53]  INFO: tweet.rb move 'start' to 'up'
I [2012-01-22 23:43:53]  INFO: tweet.rb registered 'proc_exit' event for pid 74646
I [2012-01-22 23:43:53]  INFO: tweet.rb moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb [trigger] process 74646 exited (ProcessExits)
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb move 'up' to 'start'
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb deregistered 'proc_exit' event for pid 74646
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb start: bundle exec rub /Users/Kevin/Documents/Code/Rails/work/TalkSumo/script/tweet.rb start
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb moved 'up' to 'start'
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb move 'start' to 'up'
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb registered 'proc_exit' event for pid 74648
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb moved 'start' to 'up'
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb [trigger] process 74648 exited (ProcessExits)
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb move 'up' to 'start'
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb deregistered 'proc_exit' event for pid 74648
I [2012-01-22 23:43:54]  INFO: tweet.rb start: bundle exec ruby /Users/Kevin/Documents/Code/Rails/work/TalkSumo/script/tweet.rb star
```

If I remove bundle exec and just use:

```
w.start = "ruby #{path}/tweet.rb start"
```

The error log changes to:

```
I [2012-01-23 10:41:25]  INFO: tweet.rb [ok] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2012-01-23 10:41:30]  INFO: tweet.rb [ok] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2012-01-23 10:41:35]  INFO: tweet.rb [ok] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2012-01-23 10:41:40]  INFO: tweet.rb [ok] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
I [2012-01-23 10:41:45]  INFO: tweet.rb [ok] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
```

Comment: From the log it would seem as if the daemon dies.. what happens when you run `bundle exec ruby #{path}/tweet.rb start`? Also try rewriting the god file without `bundle exec`.

Comment: Thanks for the thought.. when I run that the from the CL the process starts witha PID# assigned to it.. then running the same with stop stops it.. so idk...

Comment: I updated the original to show what happens when I remove bundle exec..

Comment: I actually found a much simple way of doing this :-|  apparently twitterstream just uses the Daemons gem which lets you set an option of ':moniter => true'.. so dont' need God in this instance.. will save me a headache now...

Comment: I'd really like to get an answer for this question :-/